# Create a Cube that asks parameters

Tags: ssas

Is there a way to create a cube in analisys services that when is query asked for a parameter?, something equivalent to an store procedure in Sql?

My need is that I have a cube but I want to filter based on an user using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you querying the cube? From which tool? Excel? Management Studio? Custom application writing the MDX?

Answer (score 0):

There are stored procedures in Analysis Services, they are implemented in .net, and the compiled assemblies then deployed, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175398.aspx.